# Fermat numbers question

Tags: fermat-numbers

I am looking for direction in my question.
The question is to prove, by long polynomial division, that:
\begin{equation} 
2^{2^{n+1}}-1\ |\ 2^{F_n-1}-1
\end{equation}

I have tried a lot of things, like calling:\begin{equation}  t=2^{2^n} \end{equation} and trying long polynomial division right away, but none of this worked successfully.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)

Comment: It would improve your setup of the problem to include a definition of Fermat number $F_n$, so that the divisibility property you want to show is framed in a clearer way.

Comment: so I need to prove that, in order to use it with Fermat numbers? because in class I remember us proving that.

Comment: I still get stuck.

Comment: Do you mean $F_{n-1}$ or $F_{n}-1$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Can't you use $2^a-1|2^b-1$ if $a|b$?

Comment: (Fn) - 1 ,and I am sorry I dont know how to use MathJax, I'll try to learn

Comment: I need to divide them via long polynomial

Comment: look for this question you"ll understand what I mean :Fermat numbers question

Comment: they didnt show how they did the polynomial division in that question, and Im asking for it.

Comment: In this question I just used the fact that in order to prove your result you just need to show that $2^{2^{n+1}}-1 \mid (2^{2^{n+1}})^{2^k}-1$ for some non negative  integer $k$. Calling $t=2^{2^{n+1}}$ you just need to show that the polynomial $t-1 \mid t^{2^k}-1$ using long division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the tip given by lulu you have $gcd(2^{2^{n+1}}-1,2^{F_n-1}-1)=2^{gcd(2^{n+1},F_n-1)}-1=2^{gcd(2^{n+1},2^{2^{n}})}-1$. Notice that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $n+1\leq 2^n$(use induction to see this). Hence $2^{n+1} \mid 2^{2^n}$ and $gcd(2^{n+1},2^{2^{n}})=2^{n+1}$. So, $gcd(2^{2^{n+1}}-1,2^{F_n-1}-1)=2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ and we have that $2^{2^{n+1}}-1 \mid 2^{F_n-1}-1$.

**Another try**
Notice (again) that $n+1\leq 2^n$. Hence there is some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(n+1)+k=2^n$. Then $2^{2^n}=2^{(n+1)+k}=2^{n+1} \cdot 2^k$. Notice then that
$$
2^{F_n-1}-1=2^{2^{2^n}}-1=2^{2^{n+1} \cdot 2^k}-1=(2^{2^{n+1}})^{2^k}-1.
$$
So, to prove that $2^{2^{n+1}}-1 \mid 2^{F_n-1}-1$  is equivalent to prove that $2^{2^{n+1}}-1 \mid (2^{2^{n+1}})^{2^k}-1$. Now call $t=2^{2^{n+1}}$ and you need to prove that $t-1 \mid t^{2^k}-1$. Can you use long division to finish this?

Comment: But I need to do that via long polynomial division.

Comment: Oh, I see. Since you said  "in class I remember us proving that" I thought you were talking about this property. I will delete the answer then if you prefer

Comment: Yes I prefer. But thank you on the time man!!!
I would like to see, if u got a direction for me to solve this via long polynomial division.

Comment: Actually, $t^{2^k}-1=(t-1)(t^{2^k-1}+t^{2^k-2} \cdots + t + 1)$.

Comment: But yes,if you do this substitution on the start you get $2^{2^{2^n}}-1=2^t-1$ and this is not a polynomial.

Comment: Oh yes yes. I forgot the 2, I am sorry. thank you!!!

Comment: That's ok! Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Yes I got it. thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to help my friend!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how to use Polynomial long division as described in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division to show that $t-1 \mid t^{2^k}-1$ let's do it.

Here the dividend is $t^{2^{k}}-1$ and the divisor is $t-1$. The first step of Polynomial long division is to divide the first term of the dividend ($t^{2^{k}}$) by the highest term of the divisor ($t$)
$$
\frac{t^{2^{k}}}{t}=t^{2^{k}-1}.
$$
Now we multiply the divisor ($t-1$) by the result just obtained ($t^{2^{k}-1}$) to get
$$
t^{2^{k}-1}(t-1)=t^{2^{k}}-t^{2^{k}-1}.
$$
Now subtract the product just obtained ($t^{2^{k}}-t^{2^{k}-1}$) from the appropriate terms of the original dividend ($t^{2^{k}}-1$) and we get $t^{2^{k}-1}-1$. Now we repeat the process with $t^{2^{k}-1}-1$ as the dividend. Repeating the process one gets $t^{(2^{k}-1)-1}-1=t^{2^{k}-2}-1$. And in the $r-1$-th step one gets $t^{2^{k}-r}-1$(prove it). Suppose WLOG that we must stop the process at this step. This means that the degree of the polynomial $t^{2^{k}-r}-1$ is smaller then the degree of the polynomial $t-1$. Since the degree of $t-1$ is $1$ we know that the degree of $t^{2^{k}-r}-1$ must be $0$. Hence we must have that $r=2^k$ and that $t^{2^{k}-r}-1=t^0-1=0$. So we have that the remainder of the long division is $0$. And we are done.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!

Comment: I am glad to help!