# Fermat numbers question.

Tags: fermat-numbers

The question is to prove, by long polynomial division, that:
$(2^{2^{(n+1)}}−1) | 2^{(Fn - 1)}−1$

$Fn = 2^{2^n}+1$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3921201/fermat-numbers-question)